# How to set size to Jtable using GridBagLayOut

Tags: java, swing, jtable, gridbaglayout

I am using GridBagLayout to position GUI components. I have used a Jtable inside a JFrame. But the table is not fitting to the frame. It appears as follows. When I drag the frame it shows the table.

[image]

Here is my code. I used this as a pop up Jframe to a button listner.

```
public class ViewPrescriptionHistory extends JFrame{

    private GridBagConstraints gridbBagConstraints;
    private JTable drugDetailsTable;
    HistroyTableModel drugDetailsTabelModel = new HistroyTableModel();

    public ViewPrescriptionHistory() {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setSize(500, 500);

        this.pack();
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        gridbBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridbBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
        gridbBagConstraints.ipady = 10;
        gridbBagConstraints.ipadx = 10;

        drugDetailsTable = new JTable(drugDetailsTabelModel);
        drugDetailsTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
        drugDetailsTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(drugDetailsTable);
        scrollPane.setBounds(5, 218, 884, 194);


        this.add(scrollPane);

    }
}

Here is my table model. I used Abstract Table model.

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel; 
    import assignment3.prescriptionsystem.model.HistoryModel;

    public class HistroyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

        private String[] columnNames = { "Doctor Name", "Date", "Drug Name", "Form" , "Dosage" };
        List<HistoryModel> historyList = new ArrayList<HistoryModel>();

        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames[column];

        }

        public int getColumnCount() {

            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {

            return historyList.size();
        }

        public void reloadDrugList(List<HistoryModel> drugsData) {
            historyList= drugsData;
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            HistoryModel drugData = historyList.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return drugData.getDocName();
            case 1:
                return drugData.getDate();
            case 2:
                return drugData.getDrugName();
            case 3:
                return drugData.getFrom();
            case 4:
                return drugData.getDosage();
            default:
                return null;

            }

        }


}
```

Here is my model class

```
public class HistoryModel {
    String docName;
    String date;
    String drugName;
    String dosage;
    String from;
    public String getDocName() {
        return docName;
    }
    public void setDocName(String docName) {
        this.docName = docName;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getDrugName() {
        return drugName;
    }
    public void setDrugName(String drugName) {
        this.drugName = drugName;
    }
    public String getDosage() {
        return dosage;
    }
    public void setDosage(String dosage) {
        this.dosage = dosage;
    }
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: We can't compile this code because we don't have `HistroyTableModel`. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should be adding your components to, and setting the GridBagLayout on, the JFrame's **content pane**, rather than the JFrame itself. Consider this image of the containment hierarchy taken from an Oracle tutorial:

[image: Container heirarchy]

You should also be calling `pack()` **after** you have added your components, **not before**:

*The pack method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes. An alternative to pack is to establish a frame size explicitly by calling setSize or setBounds (which also sets the frame location). In general, using pack is preferable to calling setSize, since pack leaves the frame layout manager in charge of the frame size, and layout managers are good at adjusting to platform dependencies and other factors that affect component size.*

Because `pack()` handles the sizing of the JFrame, you do not need to explicitly call `setSize()`

So your code should look like:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // Set the layout on the content pane rather than the JFrame

gridbBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
gridbBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
gridbBagConstraints.ipady = 10;
gridbBagConstraints.ipadx = 10;

drugDetailsTable = new JTable(drugDetailsTabelModel);
drugDetailsTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
drugDetailsTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(drugDetailsTable);
scrollPane.setBounds(5, 218, 884, 194);

getContentPane().add(scrollPane); // Add the scroll pane to the content pane rather than the JFrame

pack(); // Call pack at the end
```

And the resulting GUI looks like:

[image: GUI result]

Comment: @user3724599 if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to yourself, and the user that provided the solution. There is no obligation to do this.